# Using boost for numeric ranges

Tags: c++, for-loop, boost

I have this simple code:

```
for (auto const& i : boost::counting_range(1, 5)) {
    CString strSlipsPerPage;
    strSlipsPerPage.Format(IDS_TPL_SLIPS_PER_PAGE, i);
    m_cbStatusBarSlipsPerPage.AddString(strSlipsPerPage);
}
```

Is there any way to specify that the range is up to and including the final number? Other than increasing it to one more than you want included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [official documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/counting_range.html) and [realisation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/boost/range/counting_range.hpp) I can say no.

Comment: Thanks. It is just a little misleading because the function definition refers to `first` and `last` but `last` is not actually **last** is it? Not to worry, thanks for confirming.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, this is a convention widely used in the C++ Standard library. `last` typically refers to the element **past** the last one. Then, `last - first` gives you the number of elements in the range, and `first = last` represents the empty range.